# Iterate between the rows of a DataFrame of pandas 2 by 2

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

Let be the following DataFrame, where the time column is defined by a Python TimeDelta object:

| ID | date | direction | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-02 | IN | NaT |
| 0 | 2022-01-03 | OUT | 1 days |
| 0 | 2022-01-04 | IN | NaT |
| 0 | 2022-01-08 | OUT | 4 days |
| 1 | 2022-03-02 | IN | NaT |
| 1 | 2022-03-05 | OUT | 3 days |
| 2 | 2022-04-06 | IN | NaT |
| 2 | 2022-04-10 | OUT | 4 days |

I need to iterate over the existing DataFrame to create another one in the most efficient way containing information from rows two by two, i.e:

| ID | start_date | end_date | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-01-03 | 1 days |
| 0 | 2022-01-04 | 2022-01-08 | 4 days |
| 1 | 2022-03-02 | 2022-03-05 | 3 days |
| 2 | 2022-04-06 | 2022-04-10 | 4 days |

Assume that the original DataFrame is contained in `df`. I need a way to iterate over the rows two by two, being able to query in each iteration the information of the first row and its next one. I hope you can help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `df.loc` + `df.shift` to create final dataframe:

```py
df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": df.loc[::2, "ID"],
        "start_date": df.loc[::2, "date"],
        "end_date": df.shift(-1).loc[::2, "date"],
        "time": df.shift(-1).loc[::2, "time"],
    }
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   ID  start_date    end_date    time
0   0  2022-01-02  2022-01-03  1 days
2   0  2022-01-04  2022-01-08  4 days
4   1  2022-03-02  2022-03-05  3 days
6   2  2022-04-06  2022-04-10  4 days
```

---

Or:

```py
df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "ID": df.loc[::2, "ID"].values,
        "start_date": df.loc[::2, "date"].values,
        "end_date": df.loc[1::2, "date"].values,
        "time": df.loc[1::2, "time"].values,
    }
)
```